# Use a json file stored on fs/disk as output for an Ansible module

Tags: python, json, ansible

I am struggling with an `ansible` module I needed to create. Everything is done, the module gets a `json` file delivered from a third party onto the `fs`. This `json` file is expected to be the (only) output to be able to access to register the `json` file and access the content - or at least make the output somehow properly accessible.

The output file consists of a proper `json` file and I have tried various stuff to reach my goal.

Including:

- Simply print out the `json` file using `print` or `os.stdout.write`, because according to the documentation, `ansible` simply takes the `stdout`.
- Importing the `json` and dump is using `json.dumps(data)` or like this:

  ```
  with open('path-to-file', 'r') as tmpfile:
    data = json.load(tmpfile)
    module.exit_json(changed=True, message="API call to %s successfull" % endpoint, meta=data)
  ```

  - This ended up having the json in the output, but in an escaped variant and `ansible` refuses to access the escaped part.

What would be the correct way to make the `json` data accessible for further usage?

Edit:

The `json` looks like this (well, it’s a huge `json`, this is simply a part of it):

```
{
  "total_results": 51,
  "total_pages": 2,
  "prev_url": null,
  "next_url": "/v2/apps?order-direction=asc&page=2&results-per-page=50",
```

After `register`, the `debug` output looks like this and I cannot access `output.meta.total_results` for example.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "output": {
        "changed": true, 
        "message": "API call filtering /v2/apps with name and yes-no was successfull", 
        "meta": "{\"total_results\": 51, \"next_url\": \"/v2/apps?order-direction=asc&page=2&results-per-page=50\", \"total_pages\": 2, \"prev_url\": null, (...)
```

The `ansible` output when trying to access the var:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "output.meta.total_results": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Comment: Please provide your json file example and the error message ansible gives you. In general case, your code should work fine.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov: sure, i’ll attach it to the mainpost

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. My tests using `os.stdout.write` somehow failed, but using `print json.dumps(data)` works.

This is solved.

Comment: "`puts`"?  "`os.stdout`"?  What language were you writing this in?

Comment: well, i probably should stop switching between ruby and python. in my head. it’s `print` of course.